# Quit unexpectedly while using the libjvm.dylib plug-in

Tags: java, macos

I'm creating an application with Java 1.8 and running on Mac but 
my application have problem running on Mac OSX 10.8 always showing error "quit unexpectedly while using the libjvm.dylib plug-in"
but on other OSX runs smoothly without problem.

Here's the error...

```
Process:         java [247]
Path:            /usr/bin/java
Identifier:      net.java.openjdk.cmd
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  ??? [1]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Users/Shared/*/libjvm.dylib
PlugIn Identifier: libjvm.dylib
PlugIn Version:    ??? (1)

Date/Time:       2015-04-22 00:57:51.018 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8 (12A269)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          21289 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  1821 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   11
Anonymous UUID:                      829F8A3C-A684-4821-9CC3-7C29F828A3ED

Crashed Thread:  31  Java: QuantumRenderer-0

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_GPFLT

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d713686 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d712cf7 mach_msg + 251
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df29f23 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df2f606 __CFRunLoopRun + 1078
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df2edd2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff948c8774 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff948c8512 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff948c83a3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff938eafa3 _DPSNextEvent + 685
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff938ea862 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
10  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000019dff442a -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff938e1c03 -[NSApplication run] + 517
12  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000019dff423e +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
13  libsplashscreen.dylib           0x000000019dfd3128 __SplashInitPlatform_block_invoke_1 + 360
14  JavaNativeFoundation            0x000000019d7cfe5c +[JNFRunLoop _performCopiedBlock:] + 15
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9098c8a7 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 225
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df0c841 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df0c165 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df2f4e5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8df2edd2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
20  java                            0x000000010beba6cc CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
21  java                            0x000000010beb665c JLI_Launch + 1952
22  java                            0x000000010bebc68a main + 101
23  java                            0x000000010beb5eb4 start + 52

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d715386 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff95909ce5 pthread_join + 847
2   java                            0x000000010beb9ccc ContinueInNewThread0 + 102
3   java                            0x000000010beb72d0 ContinueInNewThread + 201
4   java                            0x000000010beb9aa1 JVMInit + 315
5   java                            0x000000010beb704e JLI_Launch + 4498
6   java                            0x000000010bebc68a main + 101
7   java                            0x000000010beba35e apple_main + 92
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9587f782 _pthread_start + 327
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9586c1c1 thread_start + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d7150fa __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff95883fc9 _pthread_cond_wait + 869
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010c46e473 Parker::park(bool, long) + 495
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010c55fd4c Unsafe_Park + 126
4   ???                             0x000000010d47a9aa 0 + 4517767594
5   ???                             0x000000010d47ade6 0 + 4517768678
6   ???                             0x000000010d08f160 0 + 4513657184
7   ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
8   ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
9   ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
10  ???                             0x000000010d08f710 0 + 4513658640
11  ???                             0x000000010d08f160 0 + 4513657184
12  ???                             0x000000010d08f710 0 + 4513658640
13  ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
14  ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
15  ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
16  ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
17  ???                             0x000000010d08f710 0 + 4513658640
18  ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
19  ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
20  ???                             0x000000010d08f98d 0 + 4513659277
21  ???                             0x000000010d0884e7 0 + 4513629415
22  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010c2e8516 JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1710
23  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010c31d58b jni_invoke_static(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*) + 447
24  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010c316785 jni_CallStaticVoidMethod + 349
25  java                            0x000000010beb7c82 JavaMain + 2456
26  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9587f782 _pthread_start + 327
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9586c1c1 thread_start + 13
```